# Write template string to .html file with Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, webpack

I've got a simple entry file called user.js like so:

```
var styles   = require('../scss/user.scss'),
    template = require('../pages/user.hbs');
    html     = template({ styles: styles });
```

And I'd like to write the contents of `html` to a .html file. Here are my loaders from the webpack.config.js file:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.hbs/,
        loader: 'file?name=[name].html!handlebars-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css?localIdentName='+ (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod' ? '__[hash:base64:5]' : '[local]__[hash:base64:5]') +'&sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions!sass?outputStyle=expanded')
    }
]
```

Using it this way, the user.hbs file is written to a user.html file, but it doesn't have the `styles` variable stuff in it.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? I need my HTML file compiled with the styles information from my scss file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) would work for you. You would push the Handlebars template to a higher level. The plugin can write the needed references for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the html-webpack-plugin but wasn't able to get the styles variables into the file. However, I'm new to Webpack so it's possible I didn't configure it correctly. I'll play around with it and mark this answer as correct if I can get it to work.

Comment: As far as I can tell with the html-webpack-plugin, there's simply no way for me to pass in the values from another loader in as variable data for a template.  Unless I'm missing something?  Do you have an example config?

Comment: It might be better to ask about that through the issue tracker of the plugin. See also https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/pull/41 .